# How to modify my reducer to get the frequency of products from the store?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm passing the product id and everything in an array..How can I get the frequency of all the items having same product id.The payload has product id ,Imageurl ,price and quantity..I added quantity later on,i thought i could use it somehow but i don't know what to do..please help[image]

```js
import {ADD_PRODUCT} from '../ActionType';
const initialState={
    product:[]
}
const productsReducer=(state=initialState,action)=>{
    const {type,payload}=action;
    switch(type)
    {
        case ADD_PRODUCT:
            return {...state,product:[...state.product,payload]};
        default:
                return state;
    }
}
export default productsReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better article to achieve your goal.
https://codehandbook.org/javascript-find-duplicate-objects-array/

Answer (score 0):

This is what i wanted,figured it out eventually

```js
import {ADD_PRODUCT,DELETE_PRODUCT} from '../ActionType';
const initialState={
    product:[]
}
const productsReducer=(state=initialState,action)=>{
    const {type,payload}=action;
    switch(type)
    {
        case ADD_PRODUCT:
            return {...state,product:[...state.product.filter(product=>product.id===payload.id?"":payload),payload]}
        default:
                return state;
    }
}
export default productsReducer;
```